# how do I fix a file not found error in visual studio and xcode

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio for mac version 17.6.3 and trying to run the maui sample project.

It works on android emulator and maccatalyst but I get NewstandKit/NewsstandKit.h file not found error as Xcode version 15_6 tries to compile it when targeting iPhone or simulator.

Has anyone been able to fix a situation like this?

In file included from  **fatal error: 'NewsstandKit/NewsstandKit.h' file not found**
**#import <NewsstandKit/NewsstandKit.h>**
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.  Contacts.Maui   C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.4.7089\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets

Answer (score 0):

According to [@rolfbjarne in Github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18493#issuecomment-1603937033), it does not support XCode 15 or higher yet.

It might work if you enable the linker by adding this into your project file:

```
<MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to use Xcode 14.3 (or earlier).

For my case, doing first suggestion caused another issue [.NET MAUI Set iOS Linker Behavior to "LinkAll" throws XamlParseException: 'Position 9:37. Cannot assign property "Source": Property does not exist.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16861)

It needs to wait for .Net8. Using Xcode 14.3 (or earlier) would be the best option at this stage.